# Multiple resolve() calls inside promise returning async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following testAsync function that should return resolved promise after I call `resolve()`.

```js
async function wait(time) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(resolve, time) });
}

async function testAsync(testParam) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            await wait(2000); // do some async work
            if (testParam === 1) {
                console.log("test param is equal to 1");
                resolve("first IF");
            }
            if (testParam < 10) {
                console.log("test param is smaller than 10");
                resolve("second IF");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}

(async () => {
    let result = await testAsync(1);
    console.log(result);
})();
```

console output:

```
test param is equal to 1
test param is smaller than 10
first IF
```

My problem is that if I structure the code in a way that includes more calls to `resolve()` that are not exclusive, the code does resolves the first one it hits but it does not stop and return in that place. Why does it continue? Is `resolve()` not loosely equal to `return`? Should I just add `return` after every `resolve()` call?

Comment: Calling resolve or reject will not exit the function (return). The rest of the code inside the function will be executed. However, further calls to resolve and reject will be ignored.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: I can’t remember where I picked this pattern up but feels good to correct something I was wrong about for months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {` is antipattern. Adding `async` in front of a function will already return a Promise. `new Promise` has to be only used to convert a none Promise base async function into one that uses a Promise.

> Is resolve() not loosely equal to return?

It is only equal in the sense, that it sets the "return" value of the promise, but it does not break the execution flow. So yes you would need to place a `return` after a resolve if you want to prevent that the following up code is executed.

But as I already said, the shown construct is anyway an anti-pattern and `testAsync` should look like this:

```
async function testAsync(testParam) {
  await wait(2000); // do some async work

  if (testParam === 1) {
    console.log("test param is equal to 1");
    return "first IF";
  }

  if (testParam < 10) {
    console.log("test param is smaller than 10");
    return "second IF";
  }
}
```

And the `wait` would more likely be written that way:

```
function wait(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(resolve, time) });
}
```

Comment: In my case, 2nd async is needed becuase I have await further down. Without it node throws an error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @miran80 I added how your shown code should look like. If you already use `await` then using `new Promise` and `resolve`/`reject` does not make sense.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I don't know why I never tried this but it looks so much better like that, less boilerplate, less indentation, it is beautiful.